# Toad for oracle error Can't initialize OCI. Error -1. Error means Oracle client command OCIEnvCreate has failed with code -1

Tags: oracle, toad, oracleclient

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXnyS.png)

The error looks like this -

```
Can't initialize OCI. Error -1

Items Checked

1. Toad bitness matches Oracle client bitness (64-bit)
2. ORACLE_HOME environment variable is not set (good).

Possible Solutions
Reinstall the Oracle client.
    • Deinstall the Oracle client.
    • Reboot.
    • Verify that HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE is removed from registry.
    • Verify that HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE is removed from registry.
    • Verify that the Oracle client folder is removed
    • Verify that OCI.DLL does not exist anywhere on your hard drive.
    • Reinstall the Oracle client.  Use a newer version if possible.

Tips
This error means that the Oracle client command "OCIEnvCreate" has failed with the result code of -1.
```

This error is seen every time I try to connect to any of the DBs on my profile.

Have tried rebooting my machine and reinstalling Toad but that did not work

Run toad with administrator privilege logs into toad but when logged in as a regular user gives same error.

Comment: So, can you connect to any database, or not? You said you reinstalled TOAD, but suggestion says that you should do that with a **client**. Did you try to do that (following instructions)?

Comment: Is the Oracle Client installed such that a regular user can run it? Or is OCI installed in such a way that only an admin user can run it?